# WinForms C# Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, error-handling, datagridview, try-catch

I know similar questions have been answered, but I'm not seeing how to apply those answers to my particular situation.

I'm populating a DataGridView and using a try...catch, but the method that's getting the data an populating the DGV is giving me the error:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvCategories.DataSource = GetData("SELECT * FROM actor");
}

public DataTable *GetData*(string selectSql)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string connString = String.Format("Server = <server>; Port = <port>; Database = <database>; User Id = <userid>; Password = <password>;");
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectSql, conn);
        conn.Close();

        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        //conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The "GetData" method name (with asterisks in the code above) has a red squiggly line and mousing over it, the message says 'Form1.GetData(string)': not all code paths return a value.

I get that the catch block needs a return (at least that's what I **think** the error is referring to), but what, exactly, do I return if all the calling method is doing is populating a DGV?

Comment: You are swallowing an exception. You have no other option but to return null. What is at stake here is, the caller does not have a chance of knowing that an exception has occured inside your method. They can only check for null. But since the caller here is the Load event handler, and since the MessageBox will be displayed to the user, the grid can be left empty I guess. What if you move the exception handling to Form_Load?

Comment: Adding `return null;` to the catch block got rid of the error, but you bring up a good point about where I'd be better off handling the exception (I'm new to error handling). Thanks, @OguzOzgul!

Answer (score 0):

You need add `return null;` codes into `catch` block.

Because if program run into `catch` block, your method will not return anything.

You need make sure your method will return a value in any case. Or if you throw a exception like `throw new Exception();`, you don't need add a `return null;` codes because the program already stop.